# Rails 4+ has_many through a has one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship

I have 3 models

1)

```
 User
 has_one :quiz
 **has_many :answers, through :quizzes**
```

2)

```
 Quiz
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :answer
```

3)

```
 Answer
 **has_one :user**
```

Is this the correct relational set up (in terms of the bolded ** lines)? In English:

I want the User to have one quiz, whereas they can answer multiple other users' quizzes with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but it seems this is what you're looking for:

```
User
  has_one :quiz
  has_many :answers
  has_many :answered_quizzes, through: :answers, source: :quiz

Quiz
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers

Answer
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the line containing answered_quizzes? Fairly new to Rails & DB so that'd be awesome. But yeah, this does look more reasonable.

Comment: That's just added, in case somewhere in the future you want to fetch all quizzes that a user has answered. It uses the answers table as a join table between the user and the quiz.